# Is there a photo that shows a iron meteor or asteroid in space in raw form having no layers of fusion crust?

Tags: solar-system, space, meteorite

A raw iron meteor or asteroid in outer space should be in its raw form having no signs of fusion crust from the friction of atmospheric entry and should therefore show distinctive signs like the posted image. 
[image: Iron Meteor Original state]

Comment: Well, one would expect definetly some surface weathering on the comet as result of particle bombardment during 4,567 Gyrs. So i doubt there are actual many comets out there with extremely high albedo ~1 that you want to see. But let's wait for an expert's opinion.

Comment: That meteorite in the pic looks etched: http://www.meteorite-times.com/articles/etching-iron-meteorites/  Widmanstätten pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widmanst%C3%A4tten_pattern

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.

The reason is that while finding meteorites on Earth is hard, finding them in space is a lot harder. A small asteroid, weighing only a few kg can't be spotted while it is still in space. The first we know of them is when they make their fiery descent.

On the other hand, there are some large asteroids that are metallic, such as [16 Psyche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16_Psyche), and we have [direct images of other large asteroids](http://www.indiana.edu/~geol105/images/gaia_chapter_2/comets_and_asteroids.htm). Metallic asteroids are relatively rare, and have a higher albedo than stony asteroids, and much more than comets. However they are not shiny balls of metal. After a few billion years in space they absorb 80% of the light that falls on them.